# Download PDF that I already Created ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, pdf

Long story short,
I want to create button that Print out PDF file to user Computer
So firstly, I create PDF file in server database / file and then I make it downloadable to user.

With this code I can create PDF file in server,
then I searched on how to make it downloadable to user..
So far no luck, most errors said "...is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected."

here's the code

```
private void cetak_pdf(string s_id, string CompanyCode , string zpath)
    {
        bool SUCCESS = true;
        string sErrMsg = "";
        string sFileName = "";

        DiskFileDestinationOptions diskOpts = null;

        try
        {
            sFileName = s_id;

            diskOpts = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();

            diskOpts.DiskFileName = Server.MapPath("~" + "\\pdf\\" + zpath + CompanyCode + "_" + sFileName + ".pdf");

            //Response.Write(diskOpts.DiskFileName);Response.End();
            // this is the file created E:\GIA_25\pdf\CompanyAddress00000003_003.pdf

            rptDoc.ExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
            rptDoc.ExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
            rptDoc.ExportOptions.DestinationOptions = diskOpts;

            rptDoc.Export();


            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            //Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyFile.pdf");
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("E:\\GIA_25\\pdf\\CompanyAddress00000003_003.pdf"));
            Response.End();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SUCCESS = false;
            sErrMsg = ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(sErrMsg);
        }
    }
```

help please, kinda new in this language

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my fault :( here is the right code for make it downloadable

```
Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";
                // String Header = "Attachment; Filename=XMLFile.xml";
                String Header = "Attachment; Filename=" + "CompanyAddress" + CompanyCode + "_" + sFileName + ".pdf";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", Header);
                System.IO.FileInfo Dfile = new System.IO.FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~" + "\\pdf\\" + "CompanyAddress" + CompanyCode + "_" + sFileName + ".pdf"));
                Response.WriteFile(Dfile.FullName);
```